# multiple update using ajax with php

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys im trying to update my database using php ang ajax, but assuming that the textbox are dynamic thats why im trying to update the database using multiple updates with one click of a button but my fire bug says that "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '100' WHERE student_id = '33' AND subject_id = '2' AND school_id = '1' AND adv' at line 1 " im not pretty sure with my code because im just experimenting on how to do it in ajax with php.

**PHP:**

```
    session_start();
    $school_id = $_SESSION['school_id'];
    $faculty_id = $_SESSION['user_id_fac'];
    $subject_id = $_POST['subject_id'];
    $year_grade_level = $_POST['year_level'];
    $subject_handeler_id = $_POST['subject_handler_id'];
    $student_grades_boy = $_POST['student_grades_boy'];
    $student_grades_girl = $_POST['student_grades_girl'];

    $update_grades_boys = "UPDATE registrar_grade_archive SET"; 

    //SET status = '0' WHERE subject_id = '$subject_id'"

    $vaues_girl = array();
    $values_boy = array();


    foreach ($student_grades_boy as $key=>$data) {
                                $student_id_B= $data['studnt_B_id'];
                                $grade_B = $data['studnt_grade_B'];

        $values_boy[$key] = 'grade = \''.$grade_B.'\' WHERE student_id = \''.$student_id_B.'\' AND subject_id = \''.$subject_id.'\' AND school_id = \''.$school_id.'\' AND advisor_faculty_id = \''.$faculty_id.'\' AND subject_handler_id = \''.$subject_handeler_id.'\' ' ;

                            }

        $values_boy = implode(', ', $values_boy);

        $ready_edit_grades_boy = $update_grades_boys . $values_boy;

        $save_grades_boy = mysql_query($ready_edit_grades_boy) or die(mysql_error());
```

please help guys. thanks in advance

Comment: are all of your IDs strings? You are wrapping then in single quotes. Integers do not need quotes. In fact all of your numbers are wrapped in quotes.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Echo this query $ready_edit_grades_boy and paste the output here so we can see

Comment: They don't need quotes, but mysql won't complain if you quote numbers.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d, or at least all students getting A++++++ on their finals

Comment: is there still a need to escaping if im validating values in jquery?

Comment: @Aoi Yes, javascript runs client-side and can be manipulated. Apart from that even valid data can break your sql if not properly escaped, like names containing a `'` character.

Answer (score 2):

Some problems here:

- if `$student_grades_boy` contains more than 1 item, your sql will have multiple `WHERE` statements (you can only have 1);
- you need a space between `SET` and the column name;
- you have a serious sql injection problem;
- you should switch to PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have no space between `SET` and `grade`.

Adding a space here should do the trick:

```
$update_grades_boys = "UPDATE registrar_grade_archive SET ";
```

If this doesn't do it, it would help tremendously if you could post the result of `echo $ready_edit_grades_boy;` and update your question.

Comment: my values are pass via ajax how will i echo it?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$update_grades_boys = "UPDATE registrar_grade_archive SET ";
```

One space is needed after `SET`..

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping vars, so it could be some ' or " in your values.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php